# As a writer, should you write because you want to write or write for your readers?

Tags: style, readers

What matters more? The story the writer wants to write or the story a reader might want to read? Choose one and state reasons.

Comment: I'm sorry; this is very broad and opinion-based. Writers.SE is meant for practical Q&A. Take our [site tour](http://writers.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how we work :)

Answer (score 4):

**The answer is "it depends".** It depends on why you are writing and the answer to that defines how and what you will write.

If you are writing for money more than the joy of writing then you are going to be looking hard at what people want to read. That's fine insofar as it goes. Maybe you can write well without having any passion behind what you are doing... Maybe. The problem you will find is that without some form of personal motivation (beyond getting paid) you work is unlikely to be imaginative and is quite likely to be middling and average.

The most financially successful works are almost always written by an author who really wanted to write. Game of Thrones does not exist because Mr Martin wanted to get paid, it exists because he really wanted to write that story.

So that brings us to "the other option" write for yourself first and hope that it pays. This can work out well. I could cite Harry Potter, Lord of the Rings, The Chronicles of Narnia, and so on and so forth. All written by a writer because that's what they wanted to write. However, I could also cite the huge slush piles in any editors office of stuff that was written that way and never saw the light of day. I could cite the huge number of really bad self-published books (or some of the pretty good ones) that are unlikely to ever earn much money.

**There is a third option**. In the Venn diagram of what the writer wants and what the reader wants is an overlap. Write in that space and it is no longer a case of what the reader wants vs what the writer wants but both at once. This is where the best chances of commercial or cult success are found.

However, the only indicator of what the reader wants is what the reader already has. So to deliberately aim for the third option there is every chance that what you are really doing is jumping on a bandwagon, probably long after any chance of being the big name there has already been and gone.

Often "what the reader wants to read" is something that not even the reader knows. No one wanted to read Lord of the Rings until Lord of the Rings came out (some might say until The Hobit, but that's a whole other debate), suddenly a whole new genre started to open up.

The odds of getting any reward for your writing other than the joy of having written is slim. Therefore, the only thing a writer can do is write for the reader that they know best - themselves. That way the motivation to finish is so much higher that the writing has a real chance of being finished and to a high standard.

*Side note: If I have just written your homework please include a credit link.*

Answer (score 2):

Write what you wish to write, which includes writing for others if and when you wish to. One caveat: In the end, there is no reward in writing anything that makes you come to despise writing, no money, no fame that can bring back what you will have forfeited, so check in with yourself along the way and remember that respectful choices are important to creativity.

Answer (score 2):

You should write what you want to write, because only with your **emotional investment** will your story have the richness that makes readers enjoy it.

But you will only be successful if *by pure chance* what you want to write coincides with what readers want to read.

If you try to write what readers want but don't enjoy writing it, you will never have more than moderate success, no more than if you wrote what you wanted but readers did not want to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Write what you want to write and what you love writing. Post it in an appropriate forum for that genre. Your followers will come. Trust me, with what I write I thought NO one would ever read it. Couple of years later I'm able to sell an E-book because I gained enough of a following.

Comment: I only write because I think I'm telling a good story.  If everyone hates the writing that is one thing...but if people hate the story (and they are legion) that's quite another. Many stories go unread and ignored even well after the author has died. But if you feel "that in the telling the story should be told" then let only History be the Judge as to whether if was worthy. Many of our greatest "tellings" have been passed on to us by word of mouth and indeed very bad writing. For example no one looks at the Star Wars Movies and sees "literature." But they do tell a good story...